# Tensorflow always showing Accuracy 1.0

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create model using Tensorflow. When I checked the accuracy of the model I always see 1.0.

I tried with multiple layers, still I'm seeing the same accuracy. Not sure where I need to tweak the model to correct this.

Below is my part of the code.

```
# Placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_features])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
              'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
          'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)
    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    import pdb;
    pdb.set_trace()
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(prediction, y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 5
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # Training the data
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for i in range(0, len(y_train) // batch_size):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = next_batch(batch_size, x_train, y_train )
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y.reshape(-1,1)})
                epoch_loss += c
                print ('Completed %d'%(i))
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'Completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)   

        #testing the data
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print ('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x:x_test, y:y_test.reshape(-1,1)}))
train_neural_network(x)
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks
Bhajesh

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your prediction results (prediction_res) are the same as the labels (y)?

```
_, c, prediction_res = sess.run([optimizer, cost, prediction], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y.reshape(-1,1)})
```

If its the same as *y* then its generating the correct outputs depending on the data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Momin Al Aziz.

Comment: The biggest problem I'm facing, I'm not able to read the data in Placeholders. When I prented all I see below.   (Pdb) tf.argmax(y,1)
<tf.Tensor 'ArgMax:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>
(Pdb) tf.argmax(prediction,1)
<tf.Tensor 'ArgMax_1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>
(Pdb) y
<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>
(Pdb) prediction
<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>                                                                                             Is there any way to read the data in placeholders.

Comment: print data like this: `_, c,data = sess.run([optimizer, cost, epoch_x], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y.reshape(-1,1)})`, here 'data` should give you the  `epoch_x ` that you are feeding

Answer (score 0):

I identify this issue. This was because I have not converted label to one-hot representation.

What I feel we have to convert label variable to one-hot representation then it will work properly. It seems like neural network expect label to be in one-hot representation.

I'm working on identifying the reason behind it. If anybody have any idea please comment.